# Passing Multiple Objects to jq for Recursive Filter Operation

Tags: jq

I am trying to use jq 1.5 to develop a script that can take one or more user inputs that represent a key and recursively remove them from JSON input.

The JSON I am referencing is here:
https://github.com/EmersonElectricCo/fsf/blob/master/docs/Test.json

My script, which seems to work pretty well, is as follows.

```
def post_recurse(f):
   def r:
      (f | select(. != null) | r), .;
      r;
def post_recurse:
   post_recurse(.[]?);
(post_recurse | objects) |= del(.META_BASIC_INFO)
```

However, I would like to replace META_BASIC_INFO with one or more user inputs. How would I go about accomplishing this? I presume with --arg from the command line, but I am unclear on how to incorporate this into my .jq script?

I've tried replacing `del(.META_BASIC_INFO)` with `del(.$module)` and invoking with `cat test.json | ./jq -f fsf_key_filter.jq --arg module META_BASIC_INFO` to test but this does not work.

Any guideance on this is greatly appreciated!

ANSWER:

Based on a couple of suggestions I was able to arrive to the following that works and users JQ.

Innvocation:

```
cat test.json | jq --argjson delete '["META_BASIC_INFO","SCAN_YARA"]' -f fsf_module_filter.jq
```

Code:

```
def post_recurse(f):
        def r:
                (f | select(. != null) | r), .;
                r;
def post_recurse:
        post_recurse(.[]?);
(post_recurse | objects) |= reduce $delete[] as $d (.; delpaths([[ $d ]]))
```

Comment: If you're referencing a variable, it should just be `$var`, not `.$var`.  If you're trying to reference a property using the variable value, you would have to index it using `.[$var]`.

Comment: No luck unfortunately, something within the del function? `jq: error: syntax error, unexpected module, expecting IDENT or __loc__ (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 7:
(post_recurse | objects) |= del(.[$module])
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use delpaths/1.  For example:

```
$ jq -n '{"a":1, "b": 1} | delpaths([["a"]])'
{
  "b": 1
}
```

That is, modifying your program so that the last line reads like this:

```
(post_recurse | objects) |= delpaths([[ $delete ]] )
```

you would invoke jq like so:

```
$ jq --arg delete "META_BASIC_INFO" -f delete.jq input.json
```

(One cannot use `--arg module ...` as "$module" has some kind of reserved status.)

Comment: That is nifty, I didn't see it documented anywhere. However, it doesn't seem to be recursive in some brief testing and I'm not sure how it addresses the user argument issue I am having.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the edit that helps. Is there a way to ensure multiple arguments that are supplied can be processed the same way? Also, what is the functional difference between `del` and `delpaths`? I can't find it in the dev manual?

Comment: (a) Multiple --arg options can appear on the command line; (b) del/1 is defined in terms of delpaths, specifically: def del(f): delpaths([path(f)]);

Comment: Mind sharing a little more on the implementation of (a)? I've done the following, `--arg delete "META_BASIC_INFO" --arg delete "SCAN_YARA"` and that only gets me half way (only the first argument is removed). I feel like there is some iteration or pattern component that I'm missing/not understanding. I've remidied this part of my question so far with a bash wrapper script to satisfy the requirement for specifying multiple arguments... but I would really like to do it in just JQ if at all possible. Thanks for sticking with me on this.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the name `module` is a keyword in 1.5 so `$module` will result in a syntax error. You should use a different name.  There are other builtins to do recursion for you, consider using them instead of churning out your own.

```
$ jq '(.. | objects | select(has($a))) |= del(.[$a])' --arg a "META_BASIC_INFO" Test.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a "one-line" solution using walk/1:

```
jq --arg d "META_BASIC_INFO" 'walk(if type == "object" then del(.[$d]) else . end)' input.json
```

If walk/1 is not in your jq, here is its definition:

```
# Apply f to composite entities recursively, and to atoms
def walk(f):
  . as $in
  | if type == "object" then
      reduce keys[] as $key
        ( {}; . + { ($key):  ($in[$key] | walk(f)) } ) | f
    elif type == "array" then map( walk(f) ) | f
    else f
    end;
```

If you want to recursively delete a bunch of key-value pairs, then here's one approach using `--argjson`:

rdelete.jq:

```
def rdelete(key):
  walk(if type == "object" then del(.[key]) else . end);

reduce $strings[] as $s (.; rdelete($s))
```

Invocation:

```
$ jq --argjson strings '["a","b"]' -f rdelete.jq input.json
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing that. I believe usage of `walk` is the ideal approach. Unfortunately, I am stuck on 1.5 and walk is not in that release. I am looking forward to the next stable release where `walk` will be included!

Comment: If you are missing `walk` you could add the definition to your filter or to your `~/.jq` file.